# Does a docker feature exist similar to save that only saves the new layer as a .tar?

Tags: docker

I have a question about whether or not a feature exists in docker: I have a local network with multiple computers (all with docker) and a local registry.  I have one base image (2.5GB) that is on every machine.  Devs on the network run a container, make modifications, and can push to registry and pull and only that new layer is downloaded.  They can save and load, and the load is almost instant because of base layer existing.  Is there any way, (`docker diff`?) that I can use an alternative to docker save that only saves that single layer to send for a smaller file transfer.  My base image is 2.5GB so each layer is trivial, but there will be real scenarios when a registry won't be available and we will have to use save/ load.  Everything works, but if we could cut 2.5GB out of each transfer, that would be amazing.

[This](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8039) is a post from 2014 asking for it but I don't think anything official became of it.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Since the link you provided is on official Docker issue tracker, I don't think there are any official solutions to this yet. What you can do is, as suggested by one post in the link, use `docker diff` to list all files changed, and use `docker cp` to copy those files and create an archive out of it. You can write a shell script, or use `docker-py`, to do that automatically.